# touchpad crashes at random times and only restarting the laptop will fix it(ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

touch-pad crashes and laptop needs restart to work again (running Ubuntu 22.04). It shows the cursor but doesn't move.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. Please edit your question to provide some additional context regarding your issue, such as: what make/model laptop are you using? Has this issue happens since installing Ubuntu, or is this a recent event? If the latter, did you make any changes to your computer (e.g., package updates/upgrades, BIOS changes, etc.)? When you say "crashes" what does this mean: do you see any error messages? You might want to run `sudo dmesg` and post the results in your question if you see anything suspicious (error messages).